# How to design a rich data table (making higher and formatting text with css)?

Tags: css, jsf, datatable, richfaces

I have a rich data table and i will make this data table more higher and plan to format text of this data table.

I have written the following css (styleclass "title"):

```
{width: 100%; font-size: 12px;padding: 4px;}
```

Now is the question how i can redesign the height of the data table in that way, that a don´t create any browser errors by showing the data table. The feature "width" is solved.

Also i will adjust text in the table, but the css feature "vertical-align:top;" doesn´t work.

Here is my current JSF Code:

```
<rich:dataTable value="#{model.templates}" var="text" styleClass="title">
    <rich:column>
       <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Dummyvalue" style="vertical-align:top;"/>
       </f:facet>
    </rich:column>

    // some other columns

</rich:dataTable>
```

Thanks for helping me !

Greetz
Marwief

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are asking. I think this may be a design question. A table will grow in length when it contains further rows. Your question makes me think that the growth of your table perhaps impacts the design of any components which surround the table.

Comment: Are you sure the align doesn't work? By default the header is as tall as the text in it, the text cannot be aligned higher.